# Process starts after I call a function even though I try to start the process first

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to learn how to use multiple processes in Python and I encountered a problem similar to the example below.
I try to start a process called `p1` using `.start()` and after that to call a function `do_something()`. The problem is that the function is called **before** the process starts.

The code I used:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def complex_calculation():
    start_timer = time.time()
    print("Started calculating...")
    [x ** 2 for x in range(20000000)]  # calculation
    print(f"complex_calculation: {time.time() - start_timer}")


def do_something():
    print(input("Enter a letter: "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=complex_calculation)
    p1.start()
    do_something()
    p1.join()
```

It seems to work if I use `time.sleep()`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=complex_calculation)
    p1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    do_something()
    p1.join()
```

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. What can I do so that I don't have to use `time.sleep()` ?

Comment: When you use multiple proceses, they run concurrently. Unless you use a synchronization mechanism, either of them can run first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, multiple processes run *concurrently*. Without doing some extra work, there are never guarantees about the order in which the processes are scheduled to run by the operating system. So while you call `p1.start()` before `do_something()`, all that means is that the Python code related to starting the process has completed before `do_something` is run. But the actual *process* represented by `p1` may run in any way relative to the remainder of the Python code. It can run entirely before, entirely after, or interleaved in *any way* with the remainder of the Python code. Relying on it being scheduled in any particular way is one definition of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

To control the way in which these processes run relative to one another, you need a synchronization primitive. There are [many ways to synchronize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#synchronization-between-processes) processes, it just depends on what you want to accomplish. If you want to make sure that the `complex_calculation` function has *started* before `do_something` is called, an [event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.Event) is probably the simplest approach. For example:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event


def complex_calculation(event):
    event.set()  # Set the event, notifying any process waiting on it
    start_timer = time.time()
    print("Started calculating...")
    [x ** 2 for x in range(20000000)]  # calculation
    print(f"complex_calculation: {time.time() - start_timer}")


def do_something(event):
    event.wait()  # Wait for `complex_calculation` to set the event
    print(input("Enter a letter: "))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = Event()
    p1 = Process(target=complex_calculation, args=(event,))
    p1.start()
    do_something(event)
    p1.join()
```

You should see something like:

```sh
$ python3 test.py
Started calculating...
Enter a letter: a
a
complex_calculation: 6.86732816696167
```